# Insert data in mongodb via form input + Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I try to insert data in mongoDB via form input. The problem is, that I'm redirecting to '/new' and receive a 'File not found' error, instead of the saying 'Successfully inserted.' I try store user information in the existing collection 'user' - after that, I would like to display the data in the form input at path '/retrieve.pug' and display it on the client side. I would deeply appreciate, if someone could assist me with this, here's my code:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var User = require('./models/user');
var app = express();

// mongodb connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/socialempireclub");
var db = mongoose.connection;

// mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

// use sessions for tracking logins
app.use(session({
  secret: 'treehouse loves you',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));

// make user ID available in templates
app.use(function (req, res, next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.session.userId;
  next();
});

// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(require('express-method-override')('method_override_param_name'));
// serve static files from /public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// include routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('File Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
// define as the last app.use callback
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

app.post('/new', function(req, res){
  new user({
    country: req.body.country
  }).save(function(err, user){
      if(err) res.json(err);
      else res.send('Sucessfully inserted');
  });
});

app.get('/retrieve', function(req, res){
    user.find({}, function(err, user){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.render('retrieve', {users: docs});
    });
});

// listen on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express app listening on port 3000');
});
```

user.js model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  country: String
});
// authenticate input against database documents
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback) {
  User.findOne({ email: email })
    .exec(function (error, user){
      if (error) {
        return callback(error);
      } else if ( !user ) {
        var err = new Error('User not found.');
        err.status = 401;
        return callback(err);
      }
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(error, result){
        if (result === true) {
          return callback(null, user);
        } else {
          return callback();
        }
      })
    });
}
// hash password before saving to database
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash){
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    user.password = hash;
    next();
  })
});
var user = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
module.exports = user;
```

profile.pug //Pug template engine // user information + form input

```
p.heading-profile Contact details
                 form(action='/new', method='POST')
                  p
                    | First name
                    input.form-control.input-first-name(type='text', placeholder='First name', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  p
                    | Last name
                    input.form-control.input-last-name(type='text', placeholder='Last name', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  p
                    | Street address
                    input.form-control.input-street-address(type='text', placeholder='Street address', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  p
                    | City
                    input.form-control.input-city(type='text', placeholder='City', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  p
                    | State/Province
                    input.form-control.input-state(type='text', placeholder='State/Province', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  p
                    | Zip/Post Code
                    input.form-control.input-zip(type='text', placeholder='Zip/Post code', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  label(for='country') Country
                    input.form-control.input-country(type='text', name='country', aria-describedby='sizing-addon3')
                  input.button(type='submit', value='Edit')
```

lastly, retrieve.pug

```
html
  head
    title Registration Form
  body
ul
each user in users
    form(action='', method='POST')
      label(for='user[email]') Email:
      input(type='text', name="user[_id]", value=user._id)
      br
      label(for='user[country]') Country:
      input(type='text', name="user[country]", value=user.country)
      br
      input(type='submit')
```

Comment: Can you post error here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, error is 'File not found'. It's displayed after hitting 'submit'-button on form input, and the route is '/new'. That's the only error I'm getting, I'm kinda clueless, how that happens.

Comment: On `/new` which pug are you rendering and where it is?

Comment: There's no 'new.pug' - file or route, after hitting submit it's redirecting to 'localhost:3000/new' and displays 'File not found error'. However, if you see in my 'app.js'-file, it should send a response on '/new' with 'Successfully inserted'. I think, either my 'app.post(...) in app.js' is wrong or the mongodb set up in 'user.js' ?!

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting the route `/new` then you have to give a page for rendering data in `POST` call as `Browser` expect that, but it does not get any page that's why you are getting this `error`.

Try to create a `new.pug` the file where all the `pug files` exists and do this

```
app.post('/new', function(req, res) {
    new user({
        country: req.body.country
    }).save(function(err, user) {
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else {
            res.render('new', {
                mesage: 'Sucessfully inserted'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

For example create `new.pug` for showing simple message

```
block content
  p Welcome to #{message}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, abdulbarik, that makes sense. I created a new file 'new.pug'. What should I write inside or display?

Comment: I just updated answer with new.pug file you can use this

Comment: I tried to insert data in mongoDB yesterday, similar to above,  but I only used the form input and sent a response on '/new' route and it successfully displayed 'Successfully inserted'. After all, the data was actually inside mongoDB. So now I tried to implement it in my web app - the same way - but it stops at 'File not found'. Therefore, I'm not sure why it worked without creating a 'new.pug' - file yesterday.

Comment: If you hit the URL from `Browser` then it always sends `GET` request and in this request you can send the response as `JSON`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks ! I tried it, as you described with 'new.pug', but I'm still stuck with 'file not found' error. Is there a way, to find out more about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

- I created two different schemas in mongoDB: 1) user 2) user_info
- Then I wired it up in my app.js, and displayed the user_info form input to the client